# Trying to compare space complexities of 2 sorting algorithms. Don't know how to interpret the answer

Tags: c, sorting, memory-management, space-complexity

I have 2 sorting algorithms, merge sort and insertion sort. I am trying to examine how much ram memory they allocate during execution, to do a comparison. Both are sorting an array of  1000 elements, integers between 0-999.

The programs are compiled to a binary called `main` (`merge_sort/main` and `insertion_sort/main`). So I am running:

```
memusage -T ./main
```

on both algorithms.

both returns:

```
heap total: 73728, heap peak: 73728, stack peak: 6144
```

Why does they return the same? Shouldn't merge sort allocate more memory than insertion sort? Am I even using `memusage` correct?

I have also tried to examine them using Valgrind, which also returns same for both:

```
==26544== HEAP SUMMARY:
==26544==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26544==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 73,728 bytes allocated
```

My theory is: that either I dont know what I am doing,

or that the list that is sorted is to small. Therefore the memory usage looks the same.

Code:

Merge sort

```
/* C program for Merge Sort */
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

// Merges two subarrays of arr[].
// First subarray is arr[l..m]
// Second subarray is arr[m+1..r]
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 = r - m;

    /* create temp arrays */
    int L[n1], R[n2];

    /* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j];

    /* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
    i = 0; // Initial index of first subarray
    j = 0; // Initial index of second subarray
    k = l; // Initial index of merged subarray
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there
    are any */
    while (i < n1)
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there
    are any */
    while (j < n2)
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

/* l is for left index and r is right index of the
sub-array of arr to be sorted */
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r)
    {
        // Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for
        // large l and h
        int m = l+(r-l)/2;

        // Sort first and second halves
        mergeSort(arr, l, m);
        mergeSort(arr, m+1, r);

        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}

/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS */
/* Function to print an array */
void printArray(int A[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {
        397, 326, 157, 581, 198, 158, 107, 479, 919, 288, 118, 14, 384, 389, 354, 905, 648, 24, 639, 279, 846, 896, 901, 491, 827, 502, 119, 520, 544, 688, 433, 542, 280, 834, 574, 739, 168, 714, 367, 547, 555, 616, 71, 583, 77, 372, 380, 414, 80, 828, 671, 900, 710, 852, 810, 471, 493, 832, 310, 579, 605, 174, 19, 576, 162, 695, 635, 851, 265, 48, 536, 228, 754, 300, 610, 272, 619, 825, 770, 147, 9, 813, 525, 135, 768, 654, 889, 446, 910, 678, 432, 172, 618, 41, 839, 589, 304, 484, 765, 357, 427, 617, 75, 683, 930, 593, 341, 149, 733, 27, 556, 474, 987, 156, 501, 665, 370, 523, 142, 420, 114, 798, 989, 382, 543, 879, 294, 305, 684, 331, 443, 383, 625, 647, 780, 811, 34, 621, 744, 842, 150, 938, 301, 495, 965, 392, 634, 358, 570, 789, 266, 242, 709, 278, 932, 57, 952, 475, 984, 136, 133, 637, 734, 207, 697, 362, 344, 332, 89, 529, 188, 164, 124, 317, 103, 257, 514, 364, 356, 203, 112, 831, 867, 644, 815, 452, 456, 260, 291, 90, 13, 21, 160, 217, 251, 459, 213, 110, 455, 56, 753, 127, 349, 884, 434, 982, 224, 410, 104, 540, 640, 973, 486, 945, 201, 166, 99, 535, 229, 725, 361, 483, 190, 743, 998, 409, 159, 102, 55, 219, 720, 33, 971, 859, 335, 887, 538, 363, 557, 696, 11, 951, 51, 845, 231, 723, 569, 63, 903, 185, 406, 505, 833, 309, 49, 599, 788, 511, 990, 196, 324, 803, 247, 970, 440, 504, 627, 205, 656, 308, 948, 690, 551, 819, 988, 608, 67, 519, 907, 510, 603, 256, 597, 880, 893, 214, 95, 270, 915, 179, 298, 378, 550, 953, 717, 321, 992, 863, 796, 868, 604, 152, 368, 15, 284, 17, 925, 808, 799, 841, 946, 974, 450, 546, 682, 91, 666, 402, 283, 736, 567, 679, 125, 299, 319, 762, 849, 785, 264, 797, 623, 401, 689, 140, 461, 171, 454, 624, 853, 724, 191, 130, 86, 451, 87, 109, 38, 61, 413, 348, 289, 829, 969, 670, 528, 588, 937, 766, 885, 237, 823, 592, 184, 73, 239, 643, 180, 10, 195, 277, 787, 431, 562, 390, 338, 146, 638, 85, 424, 652, 2, 631, 685, 405, 35, 387, 912, 333, 740, 692, 769, 66, 554, 565, 926, 223, 322, 826, 657, 858, 703, 1, 986, 312, 246, 31, 577, 323, 145, 439, 375, 39, 170, 106, 478, 978, 716, 254, 756, 37, 360, 350, 463, 269, 52, 64, 386, 509, 997, 429, 379, 655, 916, 878, 553, 794, 807, 197, 16, 840, 947, 860, 920, 963, 70, 183, 572, 763, 192, 729, 340, 238, 209, 469, 151, 167, 292, 303, 129, 847, 749, 4, 218, 216, 924, 215, 784, 243, 394, 836, 782, 476, 268, 78, 54, 590, 81, 908, 23, 704, 428, 778, 976, 680, 211, 622, 131, 273, 236, 487, 416, 767, 854, 870, 255, 837, 336, 611, 958, 233, 991, 3, 764, 83, 7, 541, 244, 792, 790, 0, 407, 418, 812, 334, 32, 872, 883, 537, 518, 72, 293, 886, 220, 866, 42, 730, 929, 891, 126, 470, 686, 329, 28, 568, 563, 659, 186, 706, 923, 497, 942, 844, 850, 492, 783, 715, 415, 153, 120, 448, 496, 468, 398, 620, 369, 373, 629, 79, 835, 711, 750, 311, 738, 346, 881, 121, 911, 50, 612, 498, 395, 955, 490, 774, 944, 506, 584, 664, 445, 173, 524, 561, 252, 713, 359, 771, 595, 96, 458, 956, 967, 422, 507, 177, 515, 342, 488, 759, 274, 275, 385, 816, 983, 306, 263, 830, 897, 760, 82, 426, 5, 698, 200, 981, 276, 559, 613, 154, 532, 735, 84, 345, 909, 94, 202, 302, 580, 508, 44, 134, 374, 898, 100, 993, 116, 712, 943, 646, 552, 975, 800, 6, 824, 328, 318, 960, 245, 708, 548, 403, 60, 931, 499, 676, 88, 894, 465, 921, 817, 693, 591, 957, 818, 721, 596, 649, 935, 261, 747, 391, 917, 314, 296, 460, 376, 412, 227, 240, 139, 871, 776, 691, 513, 93, 606, 531, 464, 694, 977, 108, 69, 259, 466, 417, 58, 737, 786, 43, 707, 933, 307, 74, 719, 653, 327, 746, 913, 262, 922, 731, 199, 494, 804, 877, 873, 732, 285, 727, 47, 210, 927, 914, 194, 758, 602, 582, 566, 941, 598, 809, 672, 966, 258, 137, 961, 902, 467, 92, 105, 316, 29, 234, 781, 675, 286, 226, 353, 857, 777, 472, 68, 985, 480, 330, 250, 248, 282, 962, 838, 176, 208, 40, 175, 178, 281, 396, 444, 436, 560, 521, 895, 366, 377, 586, 578, 212, 641, 232, 687, 571, 876, 585, 117, 101, 862, 701, 934, 939, 968, 189, 53, 677, 573, 869, 113, 642, 65, 607, 143, 979, 645, 856, 352, 20, 522, 249, 355, 148, 22, 473, 742, 98, 347, 419, 477, 705, 674, 757, 899, 430, 489, 425, 949, 726, 950, 123, 667, 399, 297, 594, 650, 587, 503, 141, 442, 748, 221, 775, 500, 339, 668, 400, 45, 814, 516, 663, 996, 772, 882, 230, 267, 722, 404, 821, 204, 755, 12, 702, 435, 822, 315, 630, 673, 848, 438, 482, 408, 928, 512, 371, 779, 626, 235, 527, 462, 904, 651, 661, 411, 752, 36, 980, 761, 485, 855, 241, 222, 287, 46, 802, 801, 206, 453, 111, 874, 295, 59, 628, 806, 290, 575, 600, 337, 728, 995, 138, 609, 875, 193, 30, 658, 558, 76, 481, 890, 745, 615, 132, 614, 795, 393, 351, 741, 564, 805, 457, 313, 545, 632, 964, 381, 25, 533, 26, 633, 62, 530, 751, 517, 936, 791, 820, 155, 940, 365, 843, 8, 918, 662, 225, 681, 388, 187, 660, 144, 793, 773, 181, 421, 161, 423, 447, 169, 994, 669, 700, 163, 526, 999, 959, 437, 449, 888, 271, 954, 18, 253, 320, 892, 864, 718, 865, 601, 699, 972, 549, 115, 441, 128, 861, 539, 165, 534, 325, 636, 122, 97, 182, 906, 343
    };
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    clock_t begin = clock();

    /* here, do your time-consuming job */
    mergeSort(arr, 0, n-1);

    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("Merge: %.10f", time_spent);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Insertion sort

```
// C program for insertion sort
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* Function to sort an array using insertion sort*/
void insertionSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, key, j;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        key = arr[i];
        j = i - 1;

        /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
        greater than key, to one position ahead
        of their current position */
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}

// A utility function to print an array of size n
void printArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

/* Driver program to test insertion sort */
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {
        397, 326, 157, 581, 198, 158, 107, 479, 919, 288, 118, 14, 384, 389, 354, 905, 648, 24, 639, 279, 846, 896, 901, 491, 827, 502, 119, 520, 544, 688, 433, 542, 280, 834, 574, 739, 168, 714, 367, 547, 555, 616, 71, 583, 77, 372, 380, 414, 80, 828, 671, 900, 710, 852, 810, 471, 493, 832, 310, 579, 605, 174, 19, 576, 162, 695, 635, 851, 265, 48, 536, 228, 754, 300, 610, 272, 619, 825, 770, 147, 9, 813, 525, 135, 768, 654, 889, 446, 910, 678, 432, 172, 618, 41, 839, 589, 304, 484, 765, 357, 427, 617, 75, 683, 930, 593, 341, 149, 733, 27, 556, 474, 987, 156, 501, 665, 370, 523, 142, 420, 114, 798, 989, 382, 543, 879, 294, 305, 684, 331, 443, 383, 625, 647, 780, 811, 34, 621, 744, 842, 150, 938, 301, 495, 965, 392, 634, 358, 570, 789, 266, 242, 709, 278, 932, 57, 952, 475, 984, 136, 133, 637, 734, 207, 697, 362, 344, 332, 89, 529, 188, 164, 124, 317, 103, 257, 514, 364, 356, 203, 112, 831, 867, 644, 815, 452, 456, 260, 291, 90, 13, 21, 160, 217, 251, 459, 213, 110, 455, 56, 753, 127, 349, 884, 434, 982, 224, 410, 104, 540, 640, 973, 486, 945, 201, 166, 99, 535, 229, 725, 361, 483, 190, 743, 998, 409, 159, 102, 55, 219, 720, 33, 971, 859, 335, 887, 538, 363, 557, 696, 11, 951, 51, 845, 231, 723, 569, 63, 903, 185, 406, 505, 833, 309, 49, 599, 788, 511, 990, 196, 324, 803, 247, 970, 440, 504, 627, 205, 656, 308, 948, 690, 551, 819, 988, 608, 67, 519, 907, 510, 603, 256, 597, 880, 893, 214, 95, 270, 915, 179, 298, 378, 550, 953, 717, 321, 992, 863, 796, 868, 604, 152, 368, 15, 284, 17, 925, 808, 799, 841, 946, 974, 450, 546, 682, 91, 666, 402, 283, 736, 567, 679, 125, 299, 319, 762, 849, 785, 264, 797, 623, 401, 689, 140, 461, 171, 454, 624, 853, 724, 191, 130, 86, 451, 87, 109, 38, 61, 413, 348, 289, 829, 969, 670, 528, 588, 937, 766, 885, 237, 823, 592, 184, 73, 239, 643, 180, 10, 195, 277, 787, 431, 562, 390, 338, 146, 638, 85, 424, 652, 2, 631, 685, 405, 35, 387, 912, 333, 740, 692, 769, 66, 554, 565, 926, 223, 322, 826, 657, 858, 703, 1, 986, 312, 246, 31, 577, 323, 145, 439, 375, 39, 170, 106, 478, 978, 716, 254, 756, 37, 360, 350, 463, 269, 52, 64, 386, 509, 997, 429, 379, 655, 916, 878, 553, 794, 807, 197, 16, 840, 947, 860, 920, 963, 70, 183, 572, 763, 192, 729, 340, 238, 209, 469, 151, 167, 292, 303, 129, 847, 749, 4, 218, 216, 924, 215, 784, 243, 394, 836, 782, 476, 268, 78, 54, 590, 81, 908, 23, 704, 428, 778, 976, 680, 211, 622, 131, 273, 236, 487, 416, 767, 854, 870, 255, 837, 336, 611, 958, 233, 991, 3, 764, 83, 7, 541, 244, 792, 790, 0, 407, 418, 812, 334, 32, 872, 883, 537, 518, 72, 293, 886, 220, 866, 42, 730, 929, 891, 126, 470, 686, 329, 28, 568, 563, 659, 186, 706, 923, 497, 942, 844, 850, 492, 783, 715, 415, 153, 120, 448, 496, 468, 398, 620, 369, 373, 629, 79, 835, 711, 750, 311, 738, 346, 881, 121, 911, 50, 612, 498, 395, 955, 490, 774, 944, 506, 584, 664, 445, 173, 524, 561, 252, 713, 359, 771, 595, 96, 458, 956, 967, 422, 507, 177, 515, 342, 488, 759, 274, 275, 385, 816, 983, 306, 263, 830, 897, 760, 82, 426, 5, 698, 200, 981, 276, 559, 613, 154, 532, 735, 84, 345, 909, 94, 202, 302, 580, 508, 44, 134, 374, 898, 100, 993, 116, 712, 943, 646, 552, 975, 800, 6, 824, 328, 318, 960, 245, 708, 548, 403, 60, 931, 499, 676, 88, 894, 465, 921, 817, 693, 591, 957, 818, 721, 596, 649, 935, 261, 747, 391, 917, 314, 296, 460, 376, 412, 227, 240, 139, 871, 776, 691, 513, 93, 606, 531, 464, 694, 977, 108, 69, 259, 466, 417, 58, 737, 786, 43, 707, 933, 307, 74, 719, 653, 327, 746, 913, 262, 922, 731, 199, 494, 804, 877, 873, 732, 285, 727, 47, 210, 927, 914, 194, 758, 602, 582, 566, 941, 598, 809, 672, 966, 258, 137, 961, 902, 467, 92, 105, 316, 29, 234, 781, 675, 286, 226, 353, 857, 777, 472, 68, 985, 480, 330, 250, 248, 282, 962, 838, 176, 208, 40, 175, 178, 281, 396, 444, 436, 560, 521, 895, 366, 377, 586, 578, 212, 641, 232, 687, 571, 876, 585, 117, 101, 862, 701, 934, 939, 968, 189, 53, 677, 573, 869, 113, 642, 65, 607, 143, 979, 645, 856, 352, 20, 522, 249, 355, 148, 22, 473, 742, 98, 347, 419, 477, 705, 674, 757, 899, 430, 489, 425, 949, 726, 950, 123, 667, 399, 297, 594, 650, 587, 503, 141, 442, 748, 221, 775, 500, 339, 668, 400, 45, 814, 516, 663, 996, 772, 882, 230, 267, 722, 404, 821, 204, 755, 12, 702, 435, 822, 315, 630, 673, 848, 438, 482, 408, 928, 512, 371, 779, 626, 235, 527, 462, 904, 651, 661, 411, 752, 36, 980, 761, 485, 855, 241, 222, 287, 46, 802, 801, 206, 453, 111, 874, 295, 59, 628, 806, 290, 575, 600, 337, 728, 995, 138, 609, 875, 193, 30, 658, 558, 76, 481, 890, 745, 615, 132, 614, 795, 393, 351, 741, 564, 805, 457, 313, 545, 632, 964, 381, 25, 533, 26, 633, 62, 530, 751, 517, 936, 791, 820, 155, 940, 365, 843, 8, 918, 662, 225, 681, 388, 187, 660, 144, 793, 773, 181, 421, 161, 423, 447, 169, 994, 669, 700, 163, 526, 999, 959, 437, 449, 888, 271, 954, 18, 253, 320, 892, 864, 718, 865, 601, 699, 972, 549, 115, 441, 128, 861, 539, 165, 534, 325, 636, 122, 97, 182, 906, 343,
    };

    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    //printf("n: %d", n);
    //printf("Unsorted array: ");
    //printArray(arr, n);
    //printf("\n");
    clock_t begin = clock();

    /* here, do your time-consuming job */
    insertionSort(arr, n);

    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    //printf("Sorted array: ");
    //printArray(arr, n);
    //printf("\n");

    printf("Inser: %.10f", time_spent);
    printf("\n");



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you're dealing with such a trivial amount of data you can't even detect the impact of the sorting algorithm. Try sorting a billion entries, not a thousand.

Comment: @tadman Yeah that was what I mentioned in my last point. A billion sound a little excessive though.

Comment: @FelixRosén If a billion sounds like a lot, start with a million, go higher until you see a difference, or conclude that there's something else up

Comment: A thousand entries is not even remotely interesting to a modern computer. It's completely, utterly inconsequential. You need to be dealing with 100e6 of them or more before things get interesting. Your computer presumably has gigabytes of memory, so benchmark harder.

Comment: Remember, most sorting algorithms perform very similarly at small values of *N*. Even the worst algorithm will seem as quick as the fastest on a handful of values. It's only when you're dealing with truly large values of *N* that the differences become quite stark. Bubble Sort on five entries happens in an instant, but on a billion entries is excruciating. You'll *feel* the problem.

Comment: You should really rerun with at least 10⁶ elements and update the question.

Comment: Also, you could add the code.

Comment: [`memusage`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/memusage.1.html) analyzes dynamic memory allocations and stack usage.  It *does not* analyze static allocations, and that might be a significant contributor to why you get the same answer.  But we can't really give you anything concrete without a [mre].

Comment: @JohnBollinger I added the code.

Comment: @Broman I added the code.

Comment: When I run your code under `memusage`, it reports "heap total: 0, heap peak: 0, stack peak: 0" for both programs.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thats wierd. I do not get that. Do you get it correctly sorted? If so, then its unlogical to get 0. What do you get for `valgrind`?

Comment: If in your insertion sort I uncomment the lines that print the final array, then a correctly-sorted result is printed.  You're not doing any dynamic allocation, so I'm not sure what light you expect `valgrind` to shine on the matter, but it reports 0 allocations and 0 frees, and (naturally) no unfreed heap blocks.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, alright I'm very new to this subject. But I do not know why yours behaves that way.

Answer (score 1):

The `memusage` and `valgrind` results you report are consistent with each other: each shows a total of 73728 bytes dynamically allocated.  And that right there should have given you pause, because ***there are no calls to dynamic memory allocation functions in your sources***.  Those bytes are not attributable to your sort functions; they must arise from allocations performed by the standard library in its setup code or in one of the few library functions you call.

Since `memusage` and the `libmemusage.so` on which it relies are provided by glibc, one would not expect them to report on glibc's own usage, and indeed, for me they don't.  I cannot explain why you see a different result, but as a wild guess, perhaps you're using mismatched versions of glibc and libmemusage.so.

BUT, you might say, what about stack usage?  Shouldn't the two approaches use different amounts of stack?  And shouldn't they use *some* stack, not 0 as reported in comments?  Here you have to understand that the underlying libmemusage operates by wrapping selected memory allocation functions, not *all* functions.  Per [the `memusage` docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/memusage.1.html), it computes stack usage like so:

> Before the first call to any ***monitored*** function, the stack pointer
>   address (base stack pointer) is saved.  After each [monitored] function call, the
>   actual stack pointer address is read and the difference from the base
>   stack pointer computed. The maximum of these differences is then the
>   stack peak.

(Emphasis added.)  Thus,

1. `memusage` provides only an *estimate* of stack usage, and that estimate is made by sampling the stack pointer around calls to monitored functions.
2. Therefore, for your particular programs, `memusage` does not report anything about your sort algorithm's stack usage, because your code makes no calls to monitored functions.

You can work around that by manually instrumenting your code so that `libmemusage` will see its stack usage.  For example, insert

```
free(malloc(0));
```

at the beginning of `main()` to ensure that a stack-usage low point is recorded, and insert calls to a function such as

```
void usage_instrumentation(void) {
    free(malloc(0));
}
```

into each of your other functions.  A function call should be used elsewhere than `main` in order to capture the stack usage of the calling function; `malloc` and `free` should be called directly in `main` to capture a low point *excluding* `main`'s usage, so that that usage is included in the final estimate.  Additionally, compile with function inlining (and maybe all optimizations) disabled to avoid this mechanism being defeated by your compiler.

If I do that then, for me, `memusage` reports 4304 bytes of stack usage for your insertion sort and 8496 for your merge sort, with the difference being slightly larger than the size of your array.  That's just as I would expect.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I am looking for. How do you compile your program? (function inlining disabled)

Comment: Sorry for disturbing, I've tried to do as you mentioned. And afterwards I run `memusage` for both. And for insertion sort i get `heap total: 73728, heap peak: 73728, stack peak: 6144` and for merge sort i get `Memory usage summary: heap total: 73728, heap peak: 73728, stack peak: 8416`. Here I should compare stack peak right? I dont get how you get such a small number on insertion sort. Perhaps its because you compile in another way.

Comment: @FelixRosén, I don't see why you should expect a stack value as large as you present for the IS, but it is no doubt related to the unexpected dynamic allocations.  Almost all of the stack usage in your program code is attributable to the array: one copy in the Insertion sort, and in the merge sort, an extra bunch of smaller arrays adding up to the size of the original.  Bottom line: your baseline is being thrown off.  As for details of how I compile, I'm using gcc 4.8 with `-O0`.  Nothing unusual.

Comment: Using a (much) larger array would perhaps make your results clearer by making the interference a smaller proportion of the result.  In other words, giving the sort routines more work to do will increase your signal-to-noise.